# Wordpress display content without page reloading

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

I have the next code:

```js
$('.left article').on('click', function(event) {
   var article_content = $(this).children('.article-content').html()
 $('.right').html(article_content);
});
```

```css
* {
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

section {
  display: flex;
}

section > div {
  flex: 0 0 50%;
  padding: 15px;
  width: 50%;
}

.left .article-content {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section>
  <div class="left">
     <article>
        <h2>My post title</h2>
        <div class="article-content"><p>This is the content for the first article</p></div>
        </article>

     <article>
        <h2>Another post title</h2>
        <div class="article-content"><p>Content for the the second post</p></div>
        </article>

     <article>
        <h2>Third post title</h2>
        <div class="article-content"><p>This is the content for the third post</p></div>
        </article>
  </div>


  <div class="right">

  </div>
</section>
```

I want to implement this using posts from custom post types, so in first column i need to display the list of titles and in the second i want to display the content of post. I did this using the next code:

```js
 <section>
        <div class="left">
            <article>
                <h2>
                    <ul>
                        <?php global $post;
                        $wpposts = get_posts('numberposts=3&post_type=>book');
                        foreach($wpposts as $post):
                            setup_postdata($post);?>
                            <li>
                                    <?php the_title(); ?>
                            </li>
                        <?php endforeach; ?>
                    </ul>
                </h2>
                <div class="article-content">
                    <p>
                    <?php the_content(); ?>
                    </p>
                </div>
            </article>
        </div>


        <div class="right">

        </div>
    </section>
```

but when i click on a link i get the whole content, and clicking the second time on a different title i dont't get the result.

Who knows what should i modify?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like your loop is incorrect. Try this:

```
 <section>
        <div class="left">
           <?php global $post;
                        $wpposts = get_posts('numberposts=3&post_type=>book');
                        foreach($wpposts as $post):
                            setup_postdata($post);?>
            <article>
                <h2>
                    <ul>
                            <li>
                                    <?php the_title(); ?>
                            </li>

                    </ul>
                </h2>
                <div class="article-content">
                    <p>
                    <?php the_content(); ?>
                    </p>
                </div>
            </article>
           <?php endforeach; ?>
        </div>


        <div class="right">

        </div>
    </section>
```

Now each post will be wrapped in `<article>`.

Comment: @designtcode, how to change the code for adding the third column (div) with the titles of posts from other constum post type(EX: testpostype), what contain a specific  tag ?

Comment: You can duplicate the `.left` column and update `post_type=>book` to `post_type=> testpostype`. I hope this makes sense?

Comment: @designtcode, yes, but if i have the next situation: i have on the left side the titles of books what have a specific tag, and by clicking on the title, besides the  content, i should get the list of posts from my (testpostype) with the same tag. How to do this?

Comment: @Asking ok I think I understand. But not sure what the tag is, how are you getting the tag? You can post another question and I can assist.